# Making labels stay at some defined position in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling, qgis-3

I am using QGIS 3.2 Bonn.

If I add a label (and I have a lot of labels, for every field, river, path, etc...) and if I zoom out all labels are crossing each other and it is hard to know what is happening then. In the first picture it is like a big mess caused when I zoom out, and the 2nd picture is an example of how I want it to stay forever.

[image: 1st picture]
[image: 2nd Picture]

Is there a way that labels will not "stick out" when I zoom out of the map, and will just stay until I zoom back in?

Comment: It would be very helpful to provide some screenshots in addition to clarify what exactly you are asking for.

Comment: Consider, whether you really need a label, or not. Street-names are usually left blank in scales smaller than 1:25.000. Path-names are definitely left blank. The numbering of parcels in ATKIS for example is only visible on scales equal and greater 1:2.500 (e.g. WMS-services MV). There is a purpose behind this omission of labels. So, don't re-invent the wheel, stick to good practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell QGIS to limit the scale ranges where it should show the labels for the features. I would probably go for the "ruled-based labelling" from QGIS. And just set some rules for showing the labels how you want.

In my example bellow I only show specific labels in scales between 1:100.000.000 and 1:10.000.000 and all the labels when I zoom in past that scale. You can have as many rules as you might need to filter out unwanted clutter, even completely hide the labels when you are zoomed way out. 
[image]

Answer (score 5):

In QGIS there is a mechanism to achive what you are after. Consider you wold like to define the position of your labels and the rotation.

Consider a point layer that looks like this:

[image]

You nee additional attributes `label_x`, `label_y` and `label_rot` (you can chose attributes name whatever you like), **Note** that all these attributes have `<NULL>` values in this example. Then, key is to use *Data defined override* for the position and rotation angel of your labels. It is defined under Placement in the labels tab:

[image]

When you turn on edit mode for this layer, you will notice that tool button in *Label toolbar* become active:

[image]

With the tools you are able to move and rotate your labels:

[image]

When saving edits, you can see that the attributes controlling position and rotation are written accordingly:

[image]