# Label overlaps when zooming out in QGIS3

Tags: qgis, labeling

I would like to have my label at a fixed distance to the object despite the zoom level.

The problem is, that I cannot really set the right place for it, as it's being constantly overlapped when zooming out and too far from my object when zooming in.

[image]

Looking on the E11 label above, you can see, that it's too far at the biggest zoom level and overlays the point, when zoomed out.

I found some solution here:
[Making labels stay at some defined position in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/300264/making-labels-stay-at-some-defined-position-in-qgis)

which states, that I must set XY coordinates for it, but I've already got them.

[image]

Is there any way to keep them at some defined position against the object?

Comment: Are you asking how to place the label e.g. 3 mm below the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the label's placement like underneath will have the label 'visually' 3 millimeters under the point (you might to make it more than 3 millimeters depending on the size of point symbology),  regardless of the scale

(again, sorry for the french ui, but things should be in the same spots)
[image]

Comment: Don't worry about french :) I would love to know this language. The problem is, that there is no impact on the label after your advice. Is there something else, what can I change here?

Comment: You might want to unset some data defined properties relative to placement which might override others, on your screenshots i can see you have set the x and y coordinates.